# Не получается сделать SQL запрос на CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Как сделать запрос `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE status 1,2` на codeigniter?
Делаю вот так:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where("clients",array("status" => "1,2"));
```

Не работает.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос - что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Это невалидный SQL-запрос. Вам нужно точное совпадение либо с 1, либо с 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->where_in('status', array(1, 2))->get('clients');
```

Если нужно было получить условие "... where status IN (1, 2)".